# How to run multiple SpecFlow scenarios using batch script?

Tags: batch-file, automation, specflow

I have visual studio 2015 professional edition and in my project there are many feature files and they contain several scenarios of specflow.

I want to run some specific scenarios(having same **tag** name) of different features using a batch script. So, How do i do that?

Comment: Write a bit of batch code doing roughly what you want and post it. Someone just might be able to help you get it right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, to run specific scenarios we will use common tag name for those scenarios and use the tag in the batch file.
Ex: Features  /include:

And after that we use the tag on another batch file(Ex: set arg1=%1). There you initialize the variable for the project. Set the packages for the project and debugger-location.

Then use it in the nunit console and run the .dll file
Ex: nunit-console "%DebuggerLocation%\%Namespace%.dll" %arg1%

Answer (score 0):

It depends which test runner you are using and which flavour Specflow generates your tests in. Basically you write a batch script to call a console tool of your test runner to run the tests.  Assuming you are using NUnit you can run them with NUnits runner as described [in the documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line) other runners will require other stuff

Comment: Thanks, http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2.5   --this also helped me a lot..